# Javascript - dynamically changing width of an element

Tags: javascript

There are a few similar questions on Stack but I think mine is the result of some syntax error on my part. Anyway, I'm building a lightbox in javascript and want to dynamically set the absolute position (`left %` css) to be half of the width of the element.

This is a snippet from the code. Full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Yab3Q/4/

```
var modal = document.getElementById(btnId+"-modal");
var modalChildren = modal.childNodes;

for (var x = 0; x<modalChildren.length; x++){
    if (!(modalChildren[x].className === "lightBox")){
        var childWidth = modalChildren[x].offsetWidth;
        var halfWidth = childWidth / 2;
        modalChildren[x].style.left = halfWidth + "px";
    }
}
```

The line `modalChildren[x].css.left = halfWidth + "px";` is returning "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined". However, `modalChildren[x].className` and `modalChildren[x].offsetWidth;` both return the expected values, so I'm unsure why I can view but not update the css here.

Comment: Do you mean this line? ` modalChildren[x].style.left = halfWidth + "px";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to alter the style properties of the following elements:

```
0: <div>
1: #text
2: <img>
3: #text
```

You can see this list for yourself by typing

```
console.log(modalChildren)
```

since a textNode does not have a style property, an error is thrown

Comment: Got it. What's the best way to exclude the `#text` from the `if` statement I have? I tried `if (!(modalChildren[x].className === "lightBox") && !(modalChildren[x].nodeType == "#text"))` but to no avail

Comment: just try this: `if (modalChildren[x].style)`

Answer (score 1):

text node has no style property:
log and check:

```
for (var x = 0; x<modalChildren.length; x++){
            console.log(modalChildren[x]);
            console.log(modalChildren[x].style);
            if (!(modalChildren[x].className === "lightBox")){
                var childWidth = modalChildren[x].offsetWidth;
                var halfWidth = childWidth / 2;
                modalChildren[x].style.left = halfWidth + "px";
            }
        }
```

Take a look at node types: http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml